# Is there a standard STL or Qt way to yield a mutex if someone else is waiting, otherwise keep it?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, stl, mutex

In my worker thread, the most convenient outer loop logic would be

```
lock (mutex_foo);

while (not done)
{
    do_some_work ();

    if (someone_is_waiting_for (mutex_foo))
    {
        unlock (mutex_foo);

        wait_until_someone_else_locks (mutex_foo);

        // expect this lock to already be taken,
        // this thread will now wait its turn
        lock (mutex_foo);
    }
}

unlock (mutex_foo);
```

the main thread would

```
while (not_done)
{
    do_stuff ();

    lock (mutex_foo); // this will interrupt the worker thread's main loop

    use_shared_resource ();

    unlock (mutex_foo);
}
```

I use C++11 and Qt 5. How should I implement this?

Comment: You can have a `std::atomic<int>` stored with the mutex, increment it before trying to lock the mutex, decrement it when unlocking. Then you can check if the value is `> 1` and you know someone else is waiting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

super's suggestion of using a std::atomic_int<> might work, but I think you may be overthinking things here -- a simpler and easier-to-verify approach for your worker thread would be this:

```
while(not done)
{
   lock_mutex();
   do_some_work();
   unlock_mutex();
}
```

This would allow other threads to get ownership of the mutex as soon as the current call to do_some_work() has returned.

If you're worried about this introducing additional locking and unlocking of the mutex, don't be -- mutexes are pretty well-optimized these days, and it's unlikely that their lock_mutex() and unlock_mutex() operations are any more expensive than your check_if_someone_is_waiting() functionality would be.

Comment: You're absolutely right. This is simpler than I thought, I had a bad model of who owns the shared data.